# Brake fluid what does it do if on ABS type plastic?

Tags: brake-fluid

What does DOT3 brake fluid do to ABS type plastic?

Comment: If you get it off quick enough nothing, otherwise it's an excellent paint remover and may degrade the plastic as well...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

DOT3 should not affect ABS plastic. It is only detrimental to natural rubber and paint. It also absorbs water, which may cause rust/corrosion in steel brake lines. Other than that, you shouldn't have any issues with it on plastic of pretty much any kind.